# Nested do catch swift 3.0

Tags: swift, error-handling, do-catch

I'd like to use consecutive try statements. If one returns an error I'd like to proceed to the next one, otherwise return the value. 
The code below seems to work fine, however I'll end up with a big nested do catch pyramid. Is there a smarter/better way to do it in Swift 3.0?

```
do {
    return try firstThing()
} catch {
    do {
        return try secondThing()
    } catch {
        return try thirdThing()
    }
}
```

Comment: do all your `try` statements inside your `do` and catch any exception in your `catch`. No need to have them nested at all.

Comment: This won't work @Pancho if the OP only wants to run second thing if firstThing fails and run thirdThing if secondThing fails.

Comment: Thanks @Pancho, but since I'm returning the value(or error) any code the first return won't be executed.

Comment: @Abizern this is true. In such case the do-catch have to be replaced by if-else or switch statement which is not going to reduce the code or make it  pretty.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the actual errors thrown from those function calls are not needed
then you can use `try?` to convert the result to an optional,
and chain the calls with the nil-coalescing operator `??`.

For example:

```
if let result = (try? firstThing()) ?? (try? secondThing()) ?? (try? thirdThing()) {
    return result
} else {
    // everything failed ...
}
```

Or, if the error from the last method should be thrown if everything fails,
use `try?` for all but the last method call:

```
return (try? firstThing()) ?? (try? secondThing()) ?? (try thirdThing())
```

Comment: I only need the last error, so this should do the job. Thanks.

Comment: Can this be adapted for void functions?

Comment: @Deco: Sure, `(try? firstThing()) ?? (try? secondThing()) ?? (try thirdThing())` calls the functions in turn until one does not throw.

Answer (score 17):

If Martin's answer is too terse for your taste you can just go with individual catch blocks.

```
do {
    return try firstThing()
} catch {}

do {
    return try secondThing()
} catch {}

do {
    return try thirdThing()
} catch {}

return defaultThing()
```

As each throwing function's result is immediately returned no nesting is necessary.

Comment: Cool, this solves it without converting to optionals. Thanks Nikolai.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is to write a function that takes all your throwing functions as an argument. It returns the first one that was successfully executed or nil.

```
func first<T>(_ values: (() throws -> T)...) -> T? {
    return values.lazy.flatMap({ (throwingFunc) -> T? in
        return try? throwingFunc()
    }).first
}
```

The **lazy** ensures that the values are only called until it finds the first match. Doing it this way, you can also add a lot of cases very quickly.

You can use the function like this

```
return first(firstThing, secondThing, thirdThing) ?? "Default"
```

I also included the code I used to test this in playground:

```
enum ThingError: Error {
    case zero
}

func firstThing() throws -> String {
    print("0")
    throw ThingError.zero
    return "0"
}

func secondThing() throws -> String {
    print("1")
    return "1"
}

func thirdThing() throws -> String {
    print("2")
    return "B"
}

func first<T>(_ values: (() throws -> T)...) -> T? {
    return values.lazy.flatMap({ (throwingFunc) -> T? in
        return try? throwingFunc()
    }).first
}

func tryThings() -> String {
    return first(firstThing, secondThing, thirdThing) ?? "Default"
}

tryThings() // prints "0" and "1"
```